# Parsing date-time input as text, without or with time-zone, into UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

We get date-time input as text, which may represent either UTC or UTC and offset, and would like to automatically Parse into UTC DateTime (i.e. skip the offset if provided).

```
Input: 2014-12-17T08:05:39 or 2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00  >>  both to UTC
```

How can we do that?

Comment: Skipping the offset returns the *local* time, not UTC. Unless the offset is *always* `0`, in which case you could just remove it, eg with `input.Remove("+00:00")`

Comment: Your first format will be interpreted by default as local time whereas the second is explicitly UTC, and even if the offset were not zero would convert automatically to a UTC DateTime..

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("2014-12-17T08:05:39", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)` this also works for string with time zone

Answer (score 1):

You can provide **2** formats in one go:

```
  string source = @"2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00";

  DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(
    source, 
    new string[] {
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz", // format with offset
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"      // format without offset
    }, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

**Edit:** If you want to *get rid* of time zone, i.e.

```
    2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00 -> 2014-12-17T08:05:39
    2014-12-17T08:05:39+11:30 -> 2014-12-17T08:05:39
    2014-12-17T08:05:39-05:00 -> 2014-12-17T08:05:39
```

you can try *regular expressions*

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    ...

    string source = @"2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00";

    source = Regex.Match(
        source, 
      @"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}T[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]+)?")
       .Value;
```

And then parse:

```
    DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(
       source, 
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Comment: DateTime.Parse can also work with `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, when the input text includes TZ the DateTime will reflect the offset when it's translated to UTC. 
Where I actually want to ignore the offset in such case...

Comment: @Guy Benhaim: if you want to ignore TZ even if it's provided, i.e. `2014-12-17T08:05:39+11:30 -> 2014-12-17T08:05:39` you can use *regular expressions* to *match* datetime part without TZ and then parse it.